AgGrid Show Error when Character Limit Reached while user is typing
In AgGrid I have a column called "Default Text" with a 500 character limit. I want to show an error message when that limit is reached as the user is typing. However, I have only been able to find ways to do so after the user hits enter or navigates away from the cell they were editing.
Here are a few methods I've tried which didn't work out for me
  onCellValueChangedAgency(event) {
    if (event.value.length == 500) {
      this._snackBar.addMessage("Warning: 500 character limit reached", 'x', {
        panelClass: [ENUM.SNACK_BAR.WARNING]
      })
    }
  }

Only checks the length after the user has navigated away from the box - thus it would be confusing on a user side
...
onCellEditingStopped: (event) => {
        if (event.value.length == 500) {
          this._snackBar.addMessage("Warning: 500 character limit reached", 'x', {
            panelClass: [ENUM.SNACK_BAR.WARNING]
          })
        }
      }

(Inside my grid init function) Same issue - only checks after user leaves cell
I tried onCellKeyPress but it only checks which key is being pressed, doesn't keep track of event.value

You could try cellKeyDown instead.
 onCellKeyDown: (event: CellKeyDownEvent) => {
    if (event.value.length == 500) {
      this._snackBar.addMessage("Warning: 500 character limit reached", 'x', {
        panelClass: [ENUM.SNACK_BAR.WARNING]
      })
    }
  }


Same problem with onCellKeyPress - there isn't an event.value

@Abby onCell key down has the value property please visit the link in my answer

That's strange, I dont see it as an option nor in the event. imgur

@Abby try setting the type of event to CellKeyDownEvent

it is set, I still don't see a value
